# SQL query: How can I get the corresponding employee id which are not allotted to department?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have `Employee` and `Department` table. How can I get the corresponding employee id which are not allotted to department?

```
Employee Table      department table    AllocatedDetails
EmpID               DeptID              AllocatedID
Name                Name                EmpID
```

Now I have to retrieve the `EmpID` which is not in the table `AllocatedDetails`.

Can anyone help me please.....

Note: I need SQL query only

Comment: can you post sample table result in each tables?

Comment: I give some Example... if ABC(Emp Name) is allocated to dept cse and his Emp ID is stored in AllocatedDetails Table now i want to reterive other Employee Details Except Employee ABC......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select empid, name
from employee
where empid not in (select empid from allocatedDetails)
```

Note this assumes the allocatedid is a deptid